# Bootstrap grid is breaking at certain points

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am making a blog app with bootstrap grid system. It works fine on small, medium and large screens. The images are below:

[image: Large screen]

[image: Medium screen]

[image: Small screen]

But between medium and small screen the grid completely breaks
[image]

Here is my HTML/ejs code. I am populating the columns from a blog model

```
<center><h1>Blogs</h1></center>

<div class="container">
   <div class="row content">
      <% blogs.forEach(function(blog){ %>
      <div class="col col-sm-2 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
         <div class="card">
            <img src="<%= blog.image %>">
            <h4><%=blog.name%></h4>
            <p><%=blog.description %></p>
            <a href="/blogs/<%= blog._id %>" class="blue-button">Read More</a>
         </div>
      </div>
      <% }); %>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS

```
.row{
    margin-top:20px;
}

 .card{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    padding:0;
    margin-top:20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius:4px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.14), 0 1px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 2px 4px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);

}
 .card:hover{
    box-shadow: 0 16px 24px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.14), 0 6px 30px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 8px 10px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    color:black;
}
.card img{
    width:100%;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    height:250px;
}
 .card h4{
    margin:20px;
}
 .card p{
    margin:20px;
    opacity: 0.65;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: 3.6em;
    line-height: 1.8em;
}
 .blue-button{
    width: 100px;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 1s , color 1s; 
    transition: background-color 1s , color 1s;
    min-height: 20px;
    background-color: #002E5B;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 4px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: lighter;
    margin: 0px 20px 15px 20px;
    padding: 5px 0px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.blue-button:hover{
    background-color: #dadada;
    color: #002E5B;
}
```

Comment: `col-sm-2`? it should be larger at small screen sizes

Comment: Thank you sir. I have no idea how I missed that

Answer (score 0):

Question was resolved in the comments:

Class `col-sm-2` needed to be changed to `col-sm-6`